# collsion detection

Tags: collision-detection

I am making a 2D bubble shooter game but m stuck on a point. I have printed those balls in a 2D space using 2D arrays. Each row has 3 inputs one is x coordinate,one is y coordinate and one is the color. 
The problem is when I shoot  the ball it goes passing the other rows of the balls. I want that  Ball to stop at the very first row of balls but it ain't doing so. I want to detect the collision of the shooter ball with the first row it face while moving and want to stop that ball the moment it collides...

Can someone get me out of this problem??.....

Comment: Which development platform are you using?

Comment: Check out this article: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109812/platformer-collision-problems/110199#110199

Comment: Hamza Hasan i am using c++ in ubuntu

Comment: Ahmet zambak thanks for article but it  is way over my head . actually i want to know the logic  that the moment a ball collides with a color ball it should stop and check wether the they are of same color then they should disappear and white balls come over there place (i mean brusting)

Comment: this is the code of array the in which i stored the balls . color and position and my ball is shooting but detecting and the bursting concept is missing

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, determining collisions with circles can be rather easy. For the sake of this example, I'm assuming your "bubbles" are perfect circles, and not oblong ellipses.

For each step of your game, you need to update the position of your fired bubble, then you need to go through your list of bubbles already on the board, determining if the fired bubble's distance to any of these is less than the radius of a bubble times two.
If the fired bubble is closer than (bubbleRadius * 2) then it must be colliding with that bubble.

[image: Image describing interaction of bubbles]